# Calculating Percent of a value within a row

Tags: r

I'm working with this data set: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkk2smhuui2cc1x/DaysPlot.csv?dl=0

And I'm trying to get the value of each "cell" value as a percent of the total of each row and each row is independent. ie: percentages are only calculated within the rows.

For example:

If row 1 has values: 1,2,3,4,5 the total = 15. 
The new output would be: 0.066, .1333, 0.2, .266, .3333

Comment: Is this strictly in R, or how do you want to process it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# toy data
df = as.data.frame(matrix(1:15, 3, 5, byrow=T))

# the operation
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD/rowSums(df)]
#            V1        V2  V3        V4        V5
# 1: 0.06666667 0.1333333 0.2 0.2666667 0.3333333
# 2: 0.15000000 0.1750000 0.2 0.2250000 0.2500000
# 3: 0.16923077 0.1846154 0.2 0.2153846 0.2307692
```

Comment: Tried your data. There could be a wrong entry under column X9.

Comment: I've never worked with the data.table package, does it provide good uses for this?

Comment: I think it's the "1,690" probably when I converted from xls to csv.